# How do you call a batch file with an argument that has quotes, using system()

Tags: c++, windows

For example, in the command line this works (the 1st argument has quotes but the 2nd argument doesn't):
"test.bat" "a" b
i.e it know that "a" is the 1st argument and b is the second

but using system() it doesn't work:
`system("test.bat" "a" b)`

this also doesn't work:
`system("test.bat" \"a\" b)`

Comment: We'd love to help. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

This is gonna be simplest if we use a raw string literal. A raw string literal is a way of writing a string in c++ where nothing gets escaped. Let's look at an example:

```
char const* myCommand = R"(test.bat "a" b)";
```

The `R` at the beginning indicates that it's a raw string literal, and if you call `system(myCommand)`, it will be exactly equivalent to typing

```
$ test.bat "a" b
```

into the command line. Now, suppose you want to escape the quotes on the command line:

```
$ test.bat \"a\" b
```

With a raw string literal, this is simple:

```
char const* myCommand = R"(test.bat \"a\" b)"; 
system(myCommand);
```

Or, alternatively:

```
system(R"(test.bat \"a\" b)");
```

Hope this helps!

**A bit more info on raw string literals:** [Raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) are a great feature, and they basically allow you to copy+paste any text directly into your program. They begin with `R`, followed by a quote and a parenthesis. Only the stuff inside the parenthesis gets included. Examples:

```
using std::string; 
string a = R"(Hello)";        // a == "Hello"
```

Begin and end with "raw":

```
string b = R"raw(Hello)raw";  // b == "Hello"
```

Begin and end with "foo"

```
string c = R"foo(Hello)foo";  // c == "Hello"
```

Begin and end with "x"

```
string d = R"x(Hello)x";      // d == "Hello"
```

The important thing is that we begin and end the literal with the same string of letters (called the delimiter), followed by the parenthesis. This ensures we never have a reason to escape something inside the raw string literal, because we can always change the delimiter so that it's not something found inside the string.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, for example:   "C:\to erase\test.bat" "a" b  works in the command line, but system(R"("C:\to erase\test.bat" "a" b)"); doesn't work. Note that system(R"("C:\to erase\test.bat" a b)");  does work but that's not what I want, and system(R"("C:\to erase\test.bat" \"a\" b)"); doesn't work either.

Comment: Could you update your question to include the exact command you want to run from the commandline, as well as the error message it gives you? (if it gives you one?)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work now:

```
system(R"(C:\"to erase\test.bat" "a")");
```

Answer (score -3):

I found the answer: `system("test.bat" ""a"" b);`

or more precisely: `system("\"test.bat\" ""a"" b");`

So the answer is to escape the quotes with a double quote

Comment: Double quotes don't escape anything. `"a""b"` is the same as `"a" "b"` which is the same as `"ab"` because string literals separated by white space concatenate.